# Haskell - A better way of keeping track of the (initial) state of a record

Tags: haskell, record, haskell-lens

I'm working on some functions that take a record and return a slightly modified record.

For example

```
import Control.Lens ((%~), (^.), (&))

modifyRecord :: SomeRecord -> SomeRecord -> SomeRecord
modifyRecord baseR currentR = currentR & thisPart %~ (fmap (someFn someValue))
        where someValue = baseR ^. thisPart
```

The function `modifyRecord` takes two arguments, both of the same type.

`currentR` is the current state of the record

and

`baseR` is the base state of the record

(i.e. No functions applied, never changed)

---

Composing several functions of this type means I'll have to compose partial functions, make a list of them

```
[fn1 baseState , fn2 baseState , fn3 baseState ... fnn baseState]
```

and then I'd fold over `currentState` with function like `foldl (flip ($))`

so each `fnn baseState` is a function in itself with type
`SomeRecord -> SomeRecord`

---

What I want to do is write those functions such that they only take the current state of the record and figure out base state on their own.

So

```
modifyRecord :: SomeRecord -> SomeRecord -> SomeRecord
```

to

```
modifyRecord :: SomeRecord -> SomeRecord
```

without actually modifying the record itself.

I want to avoid doing this

```
data SomeRecord = SomeRecord { value1 :: Float
                             , value1Base :: Float
                             , value2 :: Float
                             , value2Base :: Float
                             ...
                             ...
                             , valueN :: Float
                             , valueNBase :: Float
                             }
```

where the record itself would hold base values and function applied on it will avoid interacting with `*Base` items.

Would that be possible?

Comment: Can’t you make the base record global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the `Reader` monad.

```
modifyRecord :: SomeRecord -> Reader SomeRecord SomeRecord
modifyRecord currentR = do
     baseR <- ask
     currentR & thisPart %~ (fmap (someFn someValue))
        where someValue = baseR ^. thisPart
```

Instead of passing `baseR` as an argument to each function explicitly, you access it as part of an environment.

Then you can write something like

```
runReader (foldl (>=>) return [fn1, fn2, ..., fnn] currentR) baseR
```

1. `foldl (>=>) return [fn1, fn2, ... fnn]` reduces the list of Kleisli arrows to a single arrow, much like `foldl (.) id` composes a list of ordinary functions into a a single function.
2. Applying the result of `foldl` to `currentR` produces a `Reader SomeRecord SomeRecord` value that only needs a base record to "kick off" the chain of modifications to the original current record and producing the final result.

   (Steps 1 and 2 generalize a fixed length chain like `return currentR >>= fn1 >>= fn2 >>= fn3`.)
3. `runReader` supplies that base record by extracting the function from the `Reader` value and applying it to `baseR`.

Answer (score 2):

Put the initial state and current state in a tuple, and use `fmap` to lift functions that only care about the current state:

```
ghci> :set -XTypeApplications
ghci> fmap @((,) SomeRecord) :: (a -> b) -> (SomeRecord, a) -> (SomeRecord, b)
```

---

But what if we are given two functions in the form `(SomeRecord,SomeRecord) -> SomeRecord` and we need to compose them? We can define an operator easily enough, but does it exist somewhere already?

As it happens, the type `((,) e)` has a [`Comonad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.4/docs/Control-Comonad.html) instance. It is a very simple comonad that pairs values with some environment—in our case, the original value that we want to carry around.

The co-kleisli composition operator [`=>=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.4/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v:-61--62--61-) can be used to chain two `(SomeRecord,SomeRecord) -> SomeRecord` functions, along with [`=>>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.4/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v:-61--62--62-) to apply them to an initial paired value.

```
 ghci> import Control.Comonad
 ghci> (1,7) =>> ((\(o,c) -> c * 2) =>= (\(o,c) -> o + c))
 (1,15)
```

Or we can use `=>>` all the way:

```
 ghci> (1,7) =>> (\(o,c) -> c * 2) =>> (\(o,c) -> o + c)
 (1,15)
```

Using the flipped `fmap` operator [`<&>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--38--62-), we can even write a pipeline like

```
 ghci> (1,2) =>> (\(x,y) -> y+2) <&> succ =>> (\(x,y) -> x + y)
 (1,6)
```

We can also use [`extract`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.4/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v:extract) to get the current value, which is perhaps better than `snd` for showing intent.

Comment: And for composition?

Comment: @DanielWagner `Control.Comonad.=>=`

Comment: Perhaps you should add that to the answer body itself!

Comment: One might notice the similarity between the `Comonad` instance for pairs and the `Monad` instance for functions, which is due to isomorphism between curried and uncurried functions.

Comment: @chepner In this case I prefer the comonadic solution, because it emphasizes that a "value at rest" comes with the original attached.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, no, that is not possible: functions must explicitly declare all their inputs. Probably the cleanest way forward would be to use [`concatM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:concatM) to combine your functions. You will need to flip their arguments, so that the unmodified record comes last, not first; once you do, then you will have

```
concatM [f1, f2, f3, f4] :: SomeRecord -> SomeRecord -> SomeRecord
```

as required. For combining just two such functions, there is

```
(>=>) ::
    (SomeRecord -> SomeRecord -> SomeRecord) ->
    (SomeRecord -> SomeRecord -> SomeRecord) ->
    (SomeRecord -> SomeRecord -> SomeRecord)
```

[in `base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-); `f >=> g` will perform the modifications of `f` first, then those of `g`. If you prefer the other order, to be closer to the behavior of `(.)`, there is also a `(<=<)`.